# Can we add custom fallback image to favicon grabber API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, favicon

I have to fetch Favicons from different sites by their domain name.
I've used different APIs like

1. Google S2 => [https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=${domain}&sz=${size}](https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=$%7Bdomain%7D&sz=$%7Bsize%7D)
2. DuckDuckGo => [https://icons.duckduckgo.com/ip3/{domain}.ico](https://icons.duckduckgo.com/ip3/%7Bdomain%7D.ico)
3. Favicon kit
4. unavatar.io ( daily rate limited)

I am OK to go with Google S2 and DuckDuckGo, But their fallback icon is a problem. I wanna set my custom fallback image(can't set the `on-error` function).
I've my own favicon grabber API but I wanna use the free one first and if it gives error then use mine and if it gives error then use a fallback image
I am using Vue.js for frontend and the code is

```
 <img
 class="w-8 h-8 bg-white dark:bg-zinc-800 p-0.5 ml-1 rounded-full"
 :src="`https://icons.duckduckgo.com/ip3/${items.domain}.ico`"
 @error="$event.target.src = `My custom Favicon Grabber API`"
 loading="lazy" 
 />
```

Step what I want

1. Use a free API like Googe, DuckDuckGo at first
2. If failed, Use my Favicon Grabber API
3. If both failed, show a custom fallback image

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. *Promises* are the solution.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing today!

Comment: @RyanTaylor I used VUEUSE composable https://vueuse.org/core/useImage/#useimage to solve this issue, if you're using vue.js, you can use it.